# Apache Zeppelin Flink Interpretor can not connect Flink 1.5.2

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin

I tried to connect Flink 1.5.2 from zeppelin.

Flink cluster started on the local host.
flink-conf.yaml is default.

`/opt/flink1.5.2/current/bin/start-cluster.sh`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QCgc.png)

zeppelin
git pull and buid.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git
cd zeppelin
mvn clean package -DskipTests  -Dflink.version=1.5.2 -Pscala-2.11
bin/zeppelin-daemon start
```

interpretor setting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaEzm.png)

submit sample flink notebook

```
%flink  // let Zeppelin know what interpreter to use.

val text = benv.fromElements("In the time of chimpanzees, I was a monkey",   // some lines of text to analyze
"Butane in my veins and I'm out to cut the junkie",
"With the plastic eyeballs, spray paint the vegetables",
"Dog food stalls with the beefcake pantyhose",
"Kill the headlights and put it in neutral",
"Stock car flamin' with a loser in the cruise control",
"Baby's in Reno with the Vitamin D",
"Got a couple of couches, sleep on the love seat",
"Someone came in sayin' I'm insane to complain",
"About a shotgun wedding and a stain on my shirt",
"Don't believe everything that you breathe",
"You get a parking violation and a maggot on your sleeve",
"So shave your face with some mace in the dark",
"Savin' all your food stamps and burnin' down the trailer park",
"Yo, cut it")

/*  The meat and potatoes:
        this tells Flink to iterate through the elements, in this case strings,
        transform the string to lower case and split the string at white space into individual words
        then finally aggregate the occurrence of each word.

        This creates the count variable which is a list of tuples of the form (word, occurances)

counts.collect().foreach(println(_))  // execute the script and print each element in the counts list

*/
val counts = text.flatMap{ _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") }.map { (_,1) }.groupBy(0).sum(1)

counts.collect().foreach(println(_))  // execute the script and print each element in the counts list
```

Error

```
ERROR [2018-09-11 19:21:18,004] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:174) - Job failed
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1081)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:502)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:487)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:904)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO [2018-09-11 19:21:18,034] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:115) - Job paragraph_1536657575367_1976000602 finished by scheduler interpreter_1496279000
```

why Address already in use ??

I do not want to run the job with Flink in zeppelin.

I want to run a job with Flink that already exists.

Comment: Zeppelin 0.8 doesn't support flink 1.5, flnk 1.5 will be supported in zeppelin 0.9 which will be released by the end of this year.